# Error when Overloading the operator <<

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

```
_3DTocka operator<<(ostream& os, _3DTocka _3D){
    cout << "(" << _3D.x << "," << _3D.y << "," << _3D.z << ")" << endl;
}
```

The above is my code and it gives an error:
it must take exactly one argument (1 line)

_3DTocka is the name of the class..

Comment: Did you declare the `operator<<` as class member function?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I did not.. how do I do that?

Comment: Actually, yes, it is inside the class, in the public part. (the code in first post)

Comment: You have to declare it as free function, and usually have a `friend` declaration for it in your class.

Comment: _'the code in first post'_ which first post??

Comment: Be careful when using leading underscore, in many scopes it's reserved to the compiler/standard library implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three problems: First you're declaring the function wrong, it should return the `ostream` reference it receives as the first argument. Then it doesn't use that `ostream` argument, but is hardcoded to `cout`. Thirdly it doesn't return anything, which will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Regarding your actual compilation error, you're most likely defining the function as a member function in the class. An output operator defined as a class member is something completely different from an output operator defined as a stand-alone function: When declared as a member function it should take one argument, and it's a value to output *to the object*. If it's a stand-alone function (or defined as `friend` inside the class) then it's for outputting the object passed as the second argument "to" the object passed as the first argument.

---

Regarding the errors:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, _3DTocka _3D) {
    return os << '(' << _3D.x << ',' << _3D.y << ',' << _3D.z << ')';
}
```

A few notes:
* I have made the string literals into character literals. Handling strings is more work than handling a single character
* I now use the provided output stream, which means that you can use this for *any* kind of output stream (like files)
* I have removed the `endl`, it's not needed and should be provided by the "caller" of this function.

Now you can do

```
_3DTocka o = ...;

cout << o << endl;
```

Comment: I have it as `friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, _3DTocka _3D){` and it works now. Thanks for the correction. Also, I don't understand the part about returning anything? In the class, the teacher never mentioned it has to return something, he just gave us a similar example with cout.

Comment: @user3402189 The function isn't declared as returning `void`, in fact it *must* return the stream reference passed as first object, otherwise you will have unexpected crashes. See my updated answer.